# cut data by groups and create frequency table

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` consisting of locations and hours.

```
### dummy data
set.seed(1)
location <- c("loc1", "loc2", "loc3")
locations <- sample(location, size=50, replace=TRUE)
hours <- runif(50, min=0, max=20)

df <- data.frame(locations, hours)
```

I can cut the data into hour blocks and create a frequency table of each block

```
### cut data and create frequency table
c <- cut(df$hours, breaks=seq(0,20, by=1), include.lowest=TRUE)
t <- data.frame(table(c))
head(t)

      c Freq
1 [0,1]    0
2 (1,2]    4
3 (2,3]    2
4 (3,4]    0
5 (4,5]    4
6 (5,6]    2
```

But I can't get my head around grouping the data by locations first.

How do I use the `locations` variable to group the data to give an output like

```
  location    c Freq
1   loc1  [0,1]    x1
2   loc1  (1,2]    x2
3   loc1  (2,3]    x3
4   loc1  (3,4]    x4
5   loc1  (4,5]    x5
6   loc1  (5,6]    x6
    ...
    loc2  [0,1]    y1
    loc2  (1,2]    y2
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(hours = cut(hours, breaks=seq(0,20, by=1), include.lowest=TRUE)) %>%
  table() %>% data.frame() %>% arrange(locations, hours)
```

Which gives:

```
#  locations hours Freq
#1      loc1 [0,1]    0
#2      loc1 (1,2]    1
#3      loc1 (2,3]    1
#4      loc1 (3,4]    0
#5      loc1 (4,5]    0
#6      loc1 (5,6]    1
```

Comment: and then `table()` all that - got it :)

Comment: `%>% data.frame(table())` results in an error `nothing to tabulate`, and the `tally()` option ignores zero counts

Comment: sorry I meant `... %>% table() %>% data.frame()`

Answer (score 1):

```
t <- data.frame(table(df$locations, c))
head(t[order(t$Var1), ])


   Var1     c Freq
1  loc1 [0,1]    0
4  loc1 (1,2]    1
7  loc1 (2,3]    1
10 loc1 (3,4]    0
13 loc1 (4,5]    0
16 loc1 (5,6]    1
```

or `cbind` them first. Probably safer if you plan to work with the data later.

Comment: A nice solution that also works on my data, and quite obvious now you mention it...